# Mailchimp repeatable blocks sort order resets

Tags: html-email, mailchimp

I've created a newsletter template using one of Mailchimp's default template but I'm having an issue with the sort order of the repeatable blocks. If I try to mix different repeatable blocks, I can't do it. Is there a way to fix this?

As an example, here is a very simplified version of my initial campaign design using this template:

```
Repeatable Block 1
Repeatable Block 2
```

But if I were to create a new repeatable block for each of these, I can't order it like so:

```
Repeatable Block 1
Repeatable Block 2
Repeatable Block 1
Repeatable Block 2
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue, or constraint rather, of the MailChimp editor. It's not possible to mix different repeatable block sections.

The best option is to use the variable content blocks to achieve the effect you want.

```
<div mc:repeatable="block" mc:variant="Block 1"></div>
<div mc:repeatable="block" mc:variant="Block 2"></div>
```

This setup allows you to create as many `blocks` as you want, and change the content/layout of each block using the `variant` selector.

More info in the [MailChimp docs](http://kb.mailchimp.com/templates/basic-and-themes/repeatable-or-variable-content-blocks).

Comment: Hmm.  I guess I don't understand how this would fix the issue.  If you have four repeatable blocks, it doesn't appear that you can manually sort the order of the content of the blocks inside the Mailchimp campaign design editor.  Once you reload the page or send a test email, it just goes back to the order you added it in.

Comment: Update (from Mailchimp support): Gotcha. So, whenever you implement mc:repeatable, that first instance is considered the parent element. Any content blocks that are generated from that first instance are considered child elements, and can only be re-ordered with one another. In order to generate blocks that can be moved freely within the template, we recommend using the mc:variant tag instead, since it creates a child element from a group of pre-defined elements instead of just one.

Comment: Sounds like you're understanding it correctly. You can only reorder repeatable blocks within the parent scope. The `mc:variant` is the way to go if you need to be able to reorder blocks more freely @bkrall.

Comment: I still haven't figured this out despite reading the docs. I have added the mc:variant attribute to each of my blocks and still they can't be moved above or below each other.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was just a kind of caching issue (mailchimp displayed an old version – even after closing, reloading etc.).

I’ve deleted the campaign and created a new one with the same template. from then on everything works as expected according to http://kb.mailchimp.com/templates/code/create-editable-content-areas-with-mailchimps-template-language#Repeating-Content-Area